# How to move whole Drupal website on USB for localhost use using XAMPP?

Tags: 7, backups

My cPanel subscription will come to an end soon and I want to move my site to a USB stick or CD and still be 'runnable' / executed. It is currently on a cPanel server...

I have seen these options but they all seem outdated and might not be ideal as my website is nearly 300MB in size.

- [Static Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/static)
- [uniform server](https://www.drupal.org/node/1245206)
- [CD deploy](https://www.drupal.org/node/303458)

I want to keep the site static and lose the editing features that come with the modules - essentially I want to freeze what I have done up to now and keep a record of it that will always work locally on a medium.

Comment: There are many ways to do this, and they depend very much on your definition of 'runnable'. Do you only want only to navigate through pages and lose editing options (that is what the proposed modules do)? Or should the content creation side of the website also remain to work (in that case CD is not an option as you need to write changes to the storage medium). And why CD/USB, why not the HDD? These details might help to narrow down the question so it qualifies for reopening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are married to the idea of running your website via a USB Drive, you can always just download a lamp stack to your computer and configure it to look at usb drive as it's default home directory.

There are several options for this.

- Xampp: General one size fits all lamp stack
- DEV Desktop: A Drupal specific lamp stack
- Mamp
- Wamp

This is great for doing dev work on a duplicate copy of a site for testing in order to not screw up the production. The only problem with this is if you are trying to plug the usb to multiple computers you will have download the software each time and configure it look at the usb for it's root directory.

On the plus side using a local lamp stack you won't lose you ability to edit the site. It'll operate exactly the same way. With the exception that ftp ability will vary. Also it's good practice for doing standard Drupal Migrations.

**NOTE:** I would suggest if you try these options you operate from a desktop and not a USB. The USB could be for just keeping backups.

If this is something you deem acceptable I can expand on this idea.

Comment: Yes please! I am currently following this [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14998/turn-your-flash-drive-into-a-portable-web-server/) to install xampp on my USB --- My main concern is on how to move an existing site (i.e. as the site is at the moment) after I install Drupal on the USB... I have the backup and migrate module installed currently on it do I use this to help me? http://i.imgur.com/s1qbABn.png

Comment: @user2326637 So there's a few steps you need to take.

Obviously you need to get xampp to run from your USB. I Personally have never achieve this but I hear it's possible.

Next you should set up a **virtual host**. This basically means that you designate a directory to act as the root directory for a fake domain name you create. For example mydrupalsite.local can be typed into any browser on that computer and it will run your site. 

Last thing you do is a standard drupal migration. Details how to this can be found here. [Migrating a site](https://www.drupal.org/node/776864)

Comment: @user2326637 The quick and dirty step by step guide to installing drupal is. 1. Export old site's database using _backup and migrate_ module and zip/compress site files. 2. Unzip site files on root of new website. 3. Complete basic configuartion drupal on new site. 4.Turn on _backup and migrate_ module and import old site database export. 5. Clear all caches

Comment: @user2326637, Just checking up. How did this work for you?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - was called on other projects but Im back on this one now --- I have successfully made XAMMP work on the USB - I have installed a clean version of Drupal 7.43 on it... Do I just copy my site's folder from cPanel to the correct directory on the USB (with matching sql table in phpmyadmin) or is there something else (or better methods to use) I was thinking to install backup and migrate on the fresh install and upload my files via that... thanks

Comment: @user2326637 If you already have a fresh copy of Drupal 7 installed and it's working. Next I would move my /sites/default/files directory from cPanel to the appropriate folder on your usb. Then I would move all the modules, themes, and libraries from the /sites/all folder. This should make the Backup migrate module available to be enabled. Enable that module and restore your exported database file. 

That should be it. Unless you have a multisite. That setup is a little above my head.

Comment: after many attempts I eventually managed to do just what you said above! Many thanks for your help! + great accepted answer!